# GoogleApiClient in Android can't be register in application

Tags: android, google-maps, localization, geolocation, google-api-client

I have a big trouble in localisation by `GoogleApiClient`. I have implement intarface `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` and the `LocationListener` doesn't work at all. It seems like those interfaces haven't been registered into my app. Below is my code. Please look at method: `onLocationChanged`, `onConnectionSuspended`, `onConnected`, `onConnectionFailed`. In every example I added to print some text by `LOG` and in any of those example `logs` haven't been printed.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Location location;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LatLng latLng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds


        dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


      /* some code here */

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMapAsync(this);
            if (mMap != null) {
                //setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
        setLatLng(latLng);

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("I am here!");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);

        generateMap(getLatLng(), "3000");

        sItems.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                washLocations.clear();
                washLocations.size();
                String latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
                String longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);

                generateMap(getLatLng(), null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("location test", "tes1");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i("faild", "Location services suspended. Please reconnect.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("failds", "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("location test", "tes2");
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

As you see above:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000);
```

the map should refresh every 10 seconds - so it means also it should print `Log.d("location test", "tes2");` every 10 seconds - but it doesn't.

And here it is my `build.gradle` where I put every needed libriaries:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.micha.locationtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all creat googleApiClient object like below method

```
 private synchronized void connectToGoolgeAPIClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and after that get location like below code

```
   if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(2000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);


if (mLastLocation != null) {
double lon = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
 double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I resolved the case by changing the method into:

```
     @Override
     public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
         if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
             return;
         }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
         Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        handleNewLocation(location);
     }
```